# Is graduating on the August a problem in admission for PhD programs in the U.S.?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm studying at UCB through an off-campus program this year. My original school is University of Minnesota, and I'm applying for PhD programs in the U.S. which begin from the end of August. I found that there is a chance that I have to either take online courses during semester or spend the summer (until the beginning of August) to take liberal education courses of UMN in order to graduate. For the latter case, I will get my degree on the beginning of August, and this is much later than the norm. Is this going to be a problem in admission?

Comment: A side-note: I think just about any *acceptance* is conditional on things such as successfully graduating. If this is the case, then it hopefully won't matter. Someone on this site should have some experience on this to give you more info.

Comment: Every grad school I've ever heard of only requires you to have a degree by the time you start, so unless your grad school starts ridiculously early, you should be fine.

Comment: I'm sure that all of the programs I'll apply for begin at the end of August, so I'm relieved to hear that. Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to obtain a provisional certificate earlier if necessary. In my experience this was not an issue; the convocation was on Aug 12 and I joined grad school on Aug 23. However, you should double-check deadlines to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never hurts to specifically check with your undergraduate advisor and the desired graduate school's admission office just to make sure. My understanding is that as long as your current university acknowledges your completion of the undergraduate program (regardless of whether you physically have the Bachelor degree certificate or not) prior to you officially beginning your graduate program, then there should be no problem. But like I said, you should check in with your undergrad advisor so that they can inform you of any lingering policies or concerns.