# Finishing undergraduate degree later than mentioned on graduate school applications

Tags: graduate-admissions

I submitted all my applications for graduate school (in math) this month. I listed the date I'm expected to get my degree as May of this year. However, it has come to my attention that one of the general education requirements I'm taking this semester requires another prerequisite class. Luckily, the class I need is offered during the summer, so I can take the prerequisite class this semester and still receive my degree in August.

Would most programs be okay with me finishing up my degree in the summer, or would I have to contact them individually (either before or after acceptances come out) to make sure there won't be any issues?

Comment: This could depend on the country, I suppose. Where are you applying?

Comment: Some places will let you skip a prerequisite and some will let you take it as a co-requisite. You might ask about those..

Comment: If you are in the US, this question is a duplicate of: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/76929/75368, which offers good advice in any case.